# URLs for dependency handlers (Maven, Gradle, Ivy) through proxy

Tags: maven, gradle, proxy

In the AP Computer Science class up at my school, we get a good amount of time to work on individual coding projects.

This is great and all, but **the school's proxy blocks dependency handlers** such as Maven and Gradle.

I'm working on a fairly large project that requires Maven to handle its dependencies, and I'd really like to be able to work on it at school.

Now, I've talked to the IT guy and some of the administrators at my school and they've all said to submit a ticket with specific URLs to our Tech Admin, and they'll [quickly] submit it to the people who manage the blacklist and have them remove it.

My problem is that I don't know the specific URLs for them. The websites for the tools themselves aren't blocked, but the service (the act of the programs doing what they're supposed to) is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are default repositories for maven and gradle (as of oct 17 with their latest releases):

Maven Central - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
Gradle (jcenter) - https://jcenter.bintray.com/